# How to get django allauth google sign in to redirect to home page?

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

Hello I am using django and django all auth for authentication and am using the google feature so that when a user decides to sign in it authenticates with his google account then it will redirect him to the home page in my case to localhost:8000 in developement. But when I do try it does authenticate but instead of sending to localhost:8000 the home page it sends to this url: http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/# not sure why.
Here is my settings.py file.

```
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='/'
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='task_list'
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

any help I would appreciate Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

> The default behaviour is to redirect authenticated users to
> LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL when they try accessing login/signup pages

So all you need is to set this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: That only works for regular authentication but when I let users log in with there google accounts using django all auth it logs them in but goes to this page: http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/# and provides a page not found error not sure how to fix that